# How do i get facebbok id from mobile phone

Tags: android

Is it possible to take facebook id from other
 mobile application ?

Comment: or from mobile setting ?

Comment: yes you can ... make a dialog with textview and ask user about it :) ... in other words ... you ask wrong question

Answer (score 0):

Only if the app is storing it in a public place. Why not just use the Facebook SDK rather than relying on if a phone might have an app you might get the info you need from?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

I doubt the extent of your app is to JUST get the id if it is use a dialog as the comment above suggests. If however, you want to interact with Facebook use the Facebook SDK.